# Show interstitial ad more than once admob

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

Ive been trying to display an interstitial ad several times during my app runtime. Ive read admob documentation about it and it seems that is a one-time-use object, I'd like to know if there's any workaround for this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Same problem on Andorid plateform

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about 8 years ago but I had the same problem. What worked for me:

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
bool _isInterstitialAdReady;

void prepAd(){
  initState();
  _loadInterstitialAd();
}

void runAd() {
  _interstitialAd.show();
}

void initState() {
  _isInterstitialAdReady = false;
  _interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
    adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
    listener: _onInterstitialAdEvent,
  );
}


void _loadInterstitialAd() {
  _interstitialAd.load();
}
// TODO: Implement _onInterstitialAdEvent()
void _onInterstitialAdEvent(MobileAdEvent event) {
  switch (event) {
    case MobileAdEvent.loaded:
      _isInterstitialAdReady = true;
      break;
    case MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad:
      _isInterstitialAdReady = false;
      print('Failed to load an interstitial ad');
      break;
    case MobileAdEvent.closed:
      dispose();
      prepAd();
      break;
    default:
    // do nothing
  }
}

void dispose() {// TODO: Dispose InterstitialAd object
  _interstitialAd?.dispose();
}
```

I ran `prepAd()` once in the beginning and then just `runAd()` when I need it. You can check `_isInterstitialAdReady == true` inside `runAd()` if you want